# Python 2.7 : Where is wsdl file stored?

Tags: java, python, wsdl

I want to create a Python **RESTful** Webservice and Java Webservice Client. I am using Python 2.7. I used web.py to create webservice. On client side (Java) , I want a WSDL file to invoke Python Webservice. Where can I find it? I have configured everything on my laptop.

**Update**: I refer [Python simple example](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/python-scripting-tutorial/create-simple-rest-web-service-with-python.php) and this doesn't creates it. 
Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "where can I find it?". What did you use to generate it? I guess you didn't create it manually, otherwise you would probably know, where did you create it :)

Comment: @DawidFerenczy This is how I created Python WS. refer http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/python-scripting-tutorial/create-simple-rest-web-service-with-python.php

Comment: I didn't mean web service itself, I meant how did you generate the WSDL file (web service description)?

Comment: Regarding to "*I refer Python simple example and this doesn't creates it.*": **what** didn't create it? That article only describes how to create a simple REST web service in Python and how to execute it, there's nothing about WSDL.

Comment: BTW whatever you have used, if it doesn't work, you can try to create it manually, it would be better for learning it. It's just a [simple XML file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language).

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Oh , yes Dawid ! Thanks. Actually, I am looking for simple way to create REST webservice with WSDL  in Python. If I refer the same example ( Python simple example), do I need to create WSDL file manually? Note: I am newbie in Python. :)

Comment: See my answer. Basically WSDL is not related to Python at all. It's universal and general way of describing of an interface of your service. So doesn't matter in which language service is implemented. Just if you want to generate it automatically from a Python code, you have to use something, which know Python of course.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can always generate a url for the .wsdl file like in [this example](http://webpy.org/cookbook/webservice).

Comment: I used http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/python-scripting-tutorial/create-simple-rest-web-service-with-python.php

Answer (score 0):

I simply created org.apache.http.client.HttpClient in java to invoke this. Though, I am curious to know wsdl file location.

Comment: Don't use answers for comments, please. Put it as comment to your question, or simply update your question itself. Would be good, if you delete this answer, since it's not an answer and it will confuse other users.

Answer (score 0):

As @Avenet advised, you can use [soaplib](http://soaplib.github.io/soaplib/2_0/), which became [rpclib](https://github.com/arskom/rpclib), which in turn became [**spyne**](https://github.com/arskom/spyne). So check that, please.

People usually use the opposite workflow - they create WSDL manually and than generate stubs of code, so you have a good start, which you than extend with your business logic. Advantage is that it can generate both client and server stubs.

But both workflows should work - generating WSDL from a service, or generating code stubs from a WSDL. For learning purpose I would advice you to create WSDL manually.

Comment: Thanks. I am gonna take your advise and try writing manually.

Comment: Great, good luck! Let me know, if you'll need more help. I don't have any experience with that, but I can Google for you :) Consider marking any answer that helped you as the **answer** and upvote, please, so it's easier for other to find it.